# How to convert mp4 files into h264 via mp4parser?

Tags: decode, mp4, h.264, mp4parser

I converted some h264 files into mp4, now I want to convert them back to h264. But I didn't find the documentation for that.

Can anyone give me a hint? There is no audio part in the mp4 file. I just need the h264 file.

Here is the code that I use to convert the h264 files to mp4 files.

```
                Movie m = new Movie();
                m.addTrack(h264Track);
                Log.v(TAG, "add track to the m");
                File f =new File("/storage/sdcard0/qcom/h264_output.mp4");

                Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);
                 Log.v(TAG, "create out");
                try {
                    Log.v(TAG, "fos");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    Log.v(TAG, "write the mp4 file");
                    FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
                    out.writeContainer(fc);
                    fos.close();


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Have you find The solution ? I am looking for the answer too. Thanks